# Why my django heroku app is not getting any staticfile. [error 404]

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, static-files

Everything of my django app is working fine on local machine with debug set to false `DEBUG=False` ,but after deploying on heroku app is running but not loading any static file.On logs it's showing `status=404` for eg. `static/style.css`, for all static files.
Can anyone please guide. I'm not using whitenoise or any staticfileshandler.

my settings.py

```
 import os
 from pathlib import Path
 import django_heroku

 BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

 SECRET_KEY = 'key'

 DEBUG =False

 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1','myappname.herokuapp.com']


 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.myappConfig',
 ]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]

 ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

 TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
  },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
 }
}
import dj_database_url
db_from_env=dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
 TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
 USE_I18N = True
 USE_L10N = True
 USE_TZ = True



 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
 STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/static'),
 )


 DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['myapp.EmailBackEnd.EmailBackEnd']

 EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
 EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
 EMAIL_HOST_USER='-----@gmail.com'
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
 EMAIL_PORT='587'
 EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
 DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='------@gmail.com'
 SERVER_EMAIL = '----@gmail.com'



  django_heroku.settings(locals(), staticfiles=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't serve static file on production, so to serve your static file on production, you either serve you static with third-party web server like `nginx` or `apache2` or similar technology or you can use `aws s3 bucket`

**Also you can serve your django static files on heroku in production deploy using `whitenoise`**

Here you go for heroku docs:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Try following steps:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Be sure to add `whitenoise` to your `requirements.txt` file as well.

and modify `settings.py` file

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Simplified static file serving.
    # https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Comment: Whitenoise didn't seem to be working.whether I did or didn't get proper documentation for it,I don't know, but it didn't work for me. I was about to try other technologies you have mentioned, but as I'm already pissed off with existing one, I was hesitant to try other ones. In the mean time I got a video which solved my issue. Thanks for replying, I got to know about nginx and apache2

Comment: whitenoise is well documented, it's being used huge in heorku community

Comment: Don't know friend . But I'm happy that  my issue got fixed .This [link][1] solved all my static files issues with DEBUG set to False.


            [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFFAGdBtrRc